# Index of array looks like function name

Tags: php, laravel, stdclass

I learning about laravel and php and recently I have encountered some problem which I try  to describe:
I'm trying to echo an average age of male. I'm using this function which I found on forum related to laravel:
`$resultMale = DB::select($maleSQL, array(1));`

My problem is that it returns arrays which indexes are taken from this query

`$maleSQL = "SELECT books.name, books.book_date, AVG(reviews.age) FROM books, reviews where name='{$this->name}' and sex='m' and {$this->condition};";`

and so if I want to access to data which is indexed as "name" I use:

`echo "{$resultMale[0]->name}";`

But my problem starts when i try to access data under AVG(reviews.age)

```
 echo "{$resultMale[0]->AVG(reviews.age)}";
```

It is detected as a function inside this array not as an index.
[error in laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQL9d.png)

I've tried using foreach loop as well as:

```
 $bypassFunctionAVG="avg(reviews.age)";
 echo "{$resultMale[0]->{$bypassFunctionAVG}}";
```

I've tried also renaming this index without success.
So there goes my question: how do I echo data of this array  under this index?

Comment: You could add an alias to the column in SQL - `AVG(reviews.age) as averageAge`

Comment: I'm searching how to do that and I can't find answer. Can you tell me how to do that or give some links?

Comment: just add the `as averageAge` part as in my first comment, then have a look at your result.

Comment: i used it like this:                                                                                        
echo "<td>{$resultMale[0]->AVG(reviews.age) as averageAge}</td>";             and still didnt work

Comment: put it in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

This might work...

```
$avg = $resultMale[0]->{"AVG(reviews.age)"}
echo $avg;
```

Otherwise, try using an alias (notice, "AS avg")

```
$maleSQL = "SELECT books.name, books.book_date, AVG(reviews.age) AS avg FROM books, reviews where name='{$this->name}' and sex='m' and {$this->condition};";

echo $resultMale[0]->avg;
```

Also double quotes is not necessary to echo variables as you have done it above. They are useful in some cases but not necessary. echo $var, echo "$var", echo "{$var}" will all do the same thing.

These things will have the same result...

```
$value = 25;
echo "The value is $value.";
echo "The value is {$value}.";
echo "The value is " . $value . ".";
echo 'The value is ' . $value . '.';
```

These will not have the same result as above...

```
// use {} around non-trivial variable expressions
echo "The value is $object->value.";

// single quotes don't do anything to variables
echo 'The value is $value.';
```